# How to access the file in another folder in php

Tags: php, include

I need to include a php file to one of my file.

I have a php file like www.example.com/free/index.php.

I need to include another php file from this directory www.example.com/downloads/apple_count.php

I wrote this code inside that index.php page

```
<?php
include('..\downloads/apple_count.php');
?>
```

But it's not working.  :( It says `Warning: include(..\downloads/apple_count.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory.....`

Please help me to do this :(

Comment: Use only forward slashes `/`. Back slashes will not work on a Unix system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php on windows or linux?

if you are constantly including out of the same file you could use

```
set_include_path('/absolute/path/to/folder/');
```

either way you need to flip that ..\ into a ../

Answer (score 1):

The path you specific is relative to the current work direcotry, not the directory from where you call it, and its not resolved against the include path. Try absolute pathes

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../downloads/apple_count.php');
```

Paths starting with `/` are absolute, starting with `.` oder `..` are relative against the current work directory and everything else is resolved against the include-path.

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__) == getcwd()`. For the parent directory, you should try `dirname(getcwd())`

Comment: @MikeWarren `/../` is the better solution to resolve the path to the parent directory, else you easily end up with an infinite number of nested `dirname()`-calls

Answer (score 0):

set_include_path('/absolute/path/to/folder/');

Answer (score -2):

Are you using rewriting? Did you try `include('/downloads/apple_count.php');`

Comment: That shouldn't work, the webroot should not be the same as the file system root.

Comment: Rewriting only affects the webserver behaviour, not filesystem operations.